# How to update a table using while loops and waitfor delay to insert current date with a one second delay between records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'd like to create a table that contains two columns (id int, today datetime) and, using while loops, to insert the current date every 1 second. However, the resulting table shows the same time for all rows. Below is my code. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong, please? Thank you!

```
declare @mytable table (id int, today datetime)

declare @id int=1

declare @today datetime=getdate()


while @id<10

begin

waitfor delay '00:00:01'

insert into @mytable values (@id,@today)

set @id=@id+1

end
```

Comment: You should write `set @today = getdate()` after `waitfor delay '00:00:01'`

Comment: Why are you assigning it to a variable at all? Also why do you need this?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you so much!

Comment: What are you really trying to do there? maybe there is a better way to do it (of cource instead looping). BTW Updating a table <> Inserting data into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason every row has the same value is because you aren't setting the value of `@Today` anywhere apart from **before** your `WHILE` loop. `GETDATE()` returns a scalar value, and setting a variable to that value means it will be set the value that `GETDATE()` returned at the time the `SET` was run. The value of the variable won't change after time has passed. For example:

```
DECLARE @d datetime;
SET @d = GETDATE();
SELECT @d, GETDATE(); --Will return very similar values
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
SELECT @d, GETDATE(); --@d will have the same value as before, as its value is static, but GETDATE()'s value will have changed.
```

To do what you're after, I don't see any need for the variable for `@Today`, this *would* work fine:

```
DECLARE @mytable table (id int,
                        today datetime);

DECLARE @id int = 1;


WHILE @id < 10
BEGIN

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

    INSERT INTO @mytable
    VALUES (@id, GETDATE());

    SET @id = @id + 1;

END;
```

**However** a loop is a bad choice anyway, as an RDBMS excels at set based operations, not iterative. You would be far better to achieve what you're after by doing:

```
DECLARE @mytable table (id int,
                        today datetime);

DECLARE @id int = 1;

WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --Not actually eneded here, but shows how to increase row count
    )
INSERT INTO @mytable (id,
                      today)
SELECT TOP 10
       T.I + @ID,
       DATEADD(SECOND, T.I, GETDATE())
FROM Tally T
ORDER BY T.I;
```

This builds an inline tally table, and then inserts a value for a row for 10 ID, and adds 1 second to each incremented ID.

Comment: You're welcome @Jurij. Does the dataset approach make sense to you? It's important you understand the why it's a better approach here; especially as the code will take less than a second to run, where as your original code would take at least 9.

Comment: It does make sense, it's way more efficient. thank you again!